# Disable clearing selection in vega-lite/altair geoshape

Tags: altair, vega-lite, vega

I want to be able to select a item on a map and use that selection in other graphs and always have exactly one item selected. I thought that setting `toggle` and `clear` to `False` should assure this, but clicking outside the continent (but inside the Chart area) in my example clears the selection and selects all countries.

Is there a way to make sure there is always exactly one country selected?

PS. I know that with `empty = False` I can have an empty selection instead of a complete selection, but that's not what I'm looking for.

```
import altair as alt
import geopandas as gpd

url = "https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip"
gdf_ne = gpd.read_file(url)  # zipped shapefile
gdf_ne = gdf_ne[["NAME", "CONTINENT", "POP_EST", 'geometry']]

country_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['NAME'], value = "Tanzania", toggle = False, clear = False)

alt.Chart(gdf_ne).transform_filter(
    alt.datum["CONTINENT"] == 'Africa'
).mark_geoshape().encode(
    opacity = alt.condition(country_selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.3)),
).add_params(
    country_selection
)
```